# Python and importing sub-modules - Pandas example

Tags: python, pandas, import

I was trying to use the `pandas.tseries.holiday` module within `pandas`, but for some reason it was not showing up. I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.tseries.<TAB>
```

This does give me a list of options, but `holiday` was among them. According to the documentation of `holiday`, it should be as simple as what I tried above.

This was on my system's Python. I tried it in Jupyter using Anaconda, then in Terminal and even in Emacs, but it was never found. So it must be a general design choice that I am unaware of. I have looked for clues, but all information I find tells me that importing a whole module or parts of it is a subjective choice - example: [readability versus *name-space pollution*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187403/import-module-vs-from-module-import-function) etc.

Eventually I just tried importing it manually (the next step would have been downloading the actual `holiday` file from the [pandas git repository](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/tree/0.19.x/pandas/tseries).
So I did:

```
from pandas.tseries import holiday    # no error

holiday.<TAB>
```

... and I am shown all the stuff I need - great!

**But what is going on here??**

Looking at the [actual code of `holidays.py`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0.19.x/pandas/tseries/holiday.py) does not give me any hint as to why the file/module is not imported when I simply import pandas using the statements above.

### Edit

Here is some additional information, showing how `holiday` is not found within `pandas.tseries` itself, but can be imported and used explicitly:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.tseries.holiday.USFederalHolidayCalendar()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'pandas.tseries' has no attribute 'holiday'
>>> from pandas.tseries import holiday
>>> holiday.USFederalHolidayCalendar()
<pandas.tseries.holiday.USFederalHolidayCalendar object at 0x7f3b18dc7fd0>
```

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but it looks like you're talking about an autocomplete issue. This could be a bunch of things including your editor.

Comment: Id didn't think it would be that, seeing as hitting `<TAB>` did indeed return a lot of options, just never the `holiday` sub-module.

Comment: What editor are you using? Any specific autocomplete package?

Comment: I was first in a Jupyter notebook using my system's Python. Then tried it with the Anaconda back-end. My `PATH` includes the self-contained Anaconda modules, so it should find everything in there. Also tried it in both Terminal and Emacs. As many other sub-modules were listed, I can't see how it is editor related. The same auto-complete list appeared in all the places I tried above. None contain `pandas.tseries.holiday`.

Comment: Pandas doesn't import `tseries.holiday` in the main `__init__.py`: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/e41fe7f52a7ae6be962e683f40500624b2ba2cf6/pandas/__init__.py, so items defined in there haven't been imported, and so aren't available for tab-completion. Things like tseries.api are imported, so those can be tab-completed.

Comment: @TomAugspurger - feel free to put that great detective work into an answer and I'll accept  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using simply `import pandas as pd` does not automatically import all sub-modules of the pandas library (as pointed out by TomAugspurger in the comments above).

This is because the [`__init.py__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/e41fe7f52a7ae6be962e683f40500624b2ba2cf6/pandas/__init__.py) of the pandas library does not import the everything including the `holiday` sub-module module.

Either adapt the `__init__.py` file to do so, or be aware that one must explicitly import certain sub-modules of the pandas library!